# How to tell astyle to bracket one line for and while loops?

Tags: c++, astyle

astyle allows bracketing one line conditional statements using the option j. So, the code:

```
// test.cpp
if (x == 0) break;
```

can be formatted using the command:
**astyle -j test.cpp**
to format test.cpp as:

```
if (x == 0)
{
  break;
}
```

Suppose, I need the fragment:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) if (x == 5) break;
```

to be formatted as:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
  if (x == 5)
  {
     break;
  }
}
```

how do I accomplish it using astyle? And, similarly for while() loop?